# IndexError: ('index 87 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 70', 'occurred at index 2')

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to find the column that contain the maximum value of my 500 columns. Dataframe is below
[image]
My code is

```
c['max_point'] = c.apply(lambda x: c.columns[x.argmax()], axis = 1)
```

However, it shows the error:

```
IndexError: ('index 87 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 70', 'occurred at index 2')
```

Does anyone know how to fix?

Comment: If possible, can you update your question with your dataframe?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew I add the picture of my data head above. My data has almost 1 million records

Comment: Show copyable code, not pictures

Answer (score 0):

If you want `max_point` to contain the column number of the largest column in that row, then you were doing too much work:

```
c['max_point'] = c.idxmax(axis=1)
```

will do the job.

Comment: Hi Tim, I did that but it show `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'argmax'`

Comment: Whoops, pandas spells it differently from numpy.